# Запятые или тире

Tags: запятые, тире

Само предложение:

***Если вам подходит промокод, эти продукты остаются у вас, заменять их не будем.***

Есть ощущение, что здесь должно быть тире, но обосновать это утверждение у меня не получается.
Воспользовавшись поиском по сайту, нашла правило, которое гласит, что "эти" достаточно выделить запятой. Верна ли будет расстановка такой пунктуации:

***Если вам подходит промокод, эти продукты остаются у вас,(—) заменять их не будем.***

или

***Если вам подходит промокод, эти продукты остаются у вас (—) заменять их не будем.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***(1) Если вам подходит промокод, (2)эти продукты остаются у вас — (3)заменять их не будем.***

**Пояснение**

1. Здесь три предложения (три предикативные основы), причем предложение (1) и (2) связаны между собой, это СПП с придаточным условным.

Тире обозначает бессоюзную связь между СПП и предложением (3).  Значение присоединительное (дополнительное пояснение).

2. Другой (более простой)  вариант объяснения: предложение (3) является **присоединительной конструкцией** для СПП и обособляется тире.
3. **О запятой**

Одна запятая в БСП выражает только **распространительное** значение, а здесь этого недостаточно (нужна увеличенная пауза и тире).

Запятая и тире – это **единый знак**, в подобных случаях он не используется. Тематика его применения рассматривается отдельно (это более сложные конструкции).

Comment: Ладно, чем больше ответ, тем больше шансов получить галочку.

Comment: Увеличенная пауза — это как раз о интонационном тире.

Comment: Я просила вас дополнить свой ответ грамматическими материалами, но вы этого не сделали. вот и пришлось отвечать самой.  Увеличенная пауза – это как раз об основных знаках в БСП (выбор запятой, тире или двоеточия).  А интонация –  это как раз основное средство связи в БСП.

Comment: Здесь тире можно и не ставить (ошибкой не будет), вы его ставите исходя из интонации.

Comment: Дополнительное пояснение – это не простое распространение, поэтому требуется более СИЛЬНЫЙ знак.

Comment: О грамматических материалах никто не спрашивает. Не вижу надобности, думаю, всем и так ясно, что здесь три основы.

Comment: А как еще объяснять знаки?   У Розенталя грамматическая классификация всех тем.

Comment: Просто указать причину. А если так? *Если вам подходит промокод, заменять эти продукты не будем (?) они остаются у вас.* Нужно ли здесь тире?

Comment: Нужно здесь тире, ничего не изменилось. Мне нужно обозначить деление всего предложения на две части с помощью тире.

Comment: Мне кажется, что и без тире понятно, что там две части. Если к придаточному относится и второе, то И пишут, а не запятую.

Answer (score 2):

Интонационное тире ставится, если хочется что-то подчеркнуть. Но здесь тире заменяет запятую, а не добавляется к ней.

Но интонационное тире не характерно для делового стиля, а здесь похоже на деловой.

Comment: Т. е моё тире уместно? Стоит ли сохранять перед ним запятую?)

Comment: А почему это интонационное тире? Обозначьте, пожалуйста,  грамматику предложения.  Например, в БСП тире – это основной знак.  Или что это?  (Я бы написала "нехарактерно" слитно.)

Comment: Потому что интонационное тире — это факультативное тире, то есть то, которое ставить не обязательно. *Является нехарактерным* — нет, как-то не очень, *не является характерным* — это гуд.

Comment: @АнастасияПрокопьева Уместно, если не инструкция/объявление. Речь консультанта немного тоже имеет деловой характер. Запятую не надо оставлять. Если оставляем запятую, то получается вывод, а здесь больше не вывод, а повторение другими словами. Теоретически здесь можно, но не желательно. И это характерно для художественного стиля.

Comment: Чтобы рассуждать об интонационном тире и вообще говорить о знаках препинания, надо грамматику обозначить. Наве ваши рассуждения также нужна ссылка.